# ReactJS - first entry point

Tags: reactjs, history

I am trying to work out if a visitor is entering / first page they visit is site.com/life

As we need a change a few things like:
CSS
Audio Playing in Background
etc etc.

I am wondering is their a function that allows us to work out if a path was the first entry point for that visitor?

I was thinking we could check to see if their is a back history but not sure if this would work?

Any advice would be great.

Comment: What about creating HOC component and wrapping the whole app with it? There you would catch the initial url.

Comment: But in react (SPA) first route is `/` always ( without  programaticaly `redirect`), what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is using react-router, you can access [the history object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) and see where the oldest entry is.

Comment: I tried that but it would not do a simple console.log inside componentDidUpdate - So I can only guess it does not run.